# Class dump and CFObjects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, struct, decompiling, cfstring

Does class dump get confused by CFObjects/structs? I used class dump on an application and one of the method's argument was a struct arg1 which is a BInstantMessage:

```
struct BInstantMessage {
    void **_field1;
    struct CFString _field2;
    unsigned short *_field3;
    struct DTextStyle _field4;
    struct BUser *_field5;
    struct BChat *_field6;
};

struct CFString {
    void **_vptr$CFObject;
    struct __CFString *mCFRef;
    _Bool mIsMutable;
};

struct __CFString;
```

So, how can I get a CFStringRef or NSString* from this arg1? I am guess that class dump is replacing some CFStringRef by CFString definitions, but it's just a guess...
All I want is to get a CFStringRef from arg1 which is a BInstantMessage.

Thnaks!

Comment: CFStringRef is just a pointer to a CFString struct (typedef), and yet compatible with a NSString pointer...

Comment: So how would I, for example, NSLog _field2 in BIInstant message using arg1?

Comment: NSLog( @"%@", ( NSString * )( &( arg1._field2 ) ) );

Comment: So you log the address of the CFString, which is a CFStringRef, so a NSString *...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is using a C++ wrapper for Core Foundation objects. the `struct CFString` in `BInstantMessage` is an object of this type. You want `(NSString *)(arg1._field2.mCFRef)`.

The `void **_vptr$CFObject` field is the major hint here – it represents the vtable for a virtual superclass `CFObject` – combined with the common C++ `m` prefix naming convention.

Comment: dude that's exactly what I thought too, but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I sent you an email I found on your blog, please check it out.